Scope same instance of a class to two viewmodels with dagger hilt
I have an issue I could not find an answer to, so here I am.
I have a repository, and I am looking to scope an instance of it to two different viewmodels. When navigating from one screen, that contains said viewmodel, to the other, I want to have access to the same instance. When I move away, I would like for that instance to get destroyed.
How do I do that?
I am using jetpack compose and passing the viewmodels to the functions with viewmodel(), if it makes any difference.

use @Singleton and SingtonComponent in di module. if you don't know how, let me know
